# Developer ExactTarget Marketing Cloud account?

Tags: marketing-cloud, developer-edition

I would like to have an account to create sample App in the App Center. I am following these steps on https://code.exacttarget.com/getting-started/setting-your-development-environment.

Could you please tell me how or where  I can register for a new (developer) account ?

Comment: Hard to pick if this is a duplicate, or if the marked duplicate is the duplicate. I think I'll vote to close this one as the duplicate as the other question contains more up-to-date information.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, ExactTarget Marketing Cloud is only available through contracted purchase.  Hopefully, in the near future, we will have the ability for developers to gain limited access for development.

Comment: in addition to this answer: There's a salesforce idea on this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l1yFAAQ#.UwCeGF4QiKU.twitter  Though I have no clue that is even the correct route to express support/demand for such a request.

Comment: Believe me when I say,  I am working as hard as I can for this.

Answer (score 0):

ExactTarget Developer Editions are now available for FREE!!!!  You can go to [code.exacttarget.com](https://code.exacttarget.com/developer-edition/)  to sign up and get one.

Comment: It most certainly does give an answer to "how do I get a new account".

Comment: This is not true at the moment.  "Developer Edition is not available for registration at this time." :(